# rsync: gzip on source tolerant

Tags: rsync, gzip, transfer

I need to transfer a couple of log-files each hour to a logstorage which all users can reach, and I use rsync for do that, but the problem comes when the log-file is rotated and automatically zipped, rsync detects there is a new file and it transfered it too, that means on the destination server I have:

```
example.log.2014-01-17--00
```

and

```
example.log.2014-01-17--00.gz
```

which is the same logfile but zipped with gzip -9.

this is my rsync line, it is included into a script:

```
rsync -rvzt --include "*/" --include "$pattern" --exclude "*" $directory user@123.456.789.000:/home/user/directory/$subdir/$basefilename
```

it is executed each hour by a crontab, and it transfer all files matching a $pattern and $directory included in a file which contains paths and patterns I want to transfer.

So my question is if there is an rsync option that I have not seen, or if there is some posibility to do that and how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Andryoid - Reading the `--include`/`--exclude` sequence:  get all subfolders `*/`, only with pattern `$pattern`, but then exclude everything `*`?  Did I interpret the intent, and if so, that doesn't sound right.  Wouldn't it be, get all subfolders `*/`, only with pattern `$pattern`, but then strip off files with `.gz`, which would be:  `--exclude "*.gz"`.  Without def's for `$subdir`, `$basefilename`, and example path - pretty much a complete example, that's what I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using rsyslog forwarding [1]?

Also, from [2], it looks like adding `--exclude '*.gz'` should fix your issue. Why do you `--exclude '*'`? My reading of that would be that every file is excluded from the sync.

[1] http://www.rsyslog.com/storing-and-forwarding-remote-messages/

[2] http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/